# JavaFX - file (video) upload

Tags: java

I asked this question before but it was unanswered for a week or so I think so I decided to ask again but with a different formula.

I have a JFX desktop app. one of the features of one of the modules contains a video upload to the server. I searched this around a lot but the solutions I found are in two categories

- using servlet / jsp on the server and service in the desktop app
- copying the file locally (not what I want)

now I am ok with havign a service doing it the upload that's what I expect but I dont see the need of having a deployment on the server plus I already have a webapp. Is it possible to just have a webservice in the server and call it in the desktop app code? I haven't found anything on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible and preferable choice.

The potential solution I see would be:

deploy a file REST service on your File server where the videos would be held.
Example Rest service in Java: https://github.com/polopolyps/fileserver

Then in your java FX application you simply send user file (a video) using REST lib, see: http://square.github.io/retrofit/

and Voila you have your functionality.